# How to extend Flow function type with additional properties

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

Flow v0.57

I'd like to define 2 function types, `Foo` and `FancyFoo` to help type check the following pattern:

```
const fooFn = () => ({ id: '...', type: '...' });

fooFn['HELLO'] = 'WORLD';
fooFn['test'] = () => {};

...

// now I can do this:
fooFn();
fooFn.HELLO;
fooFn.test();
```

The first function type is seemingly straightforward:

```
type Foo = () => {
  id :string,
  type :string
}
```

I'm stuck figuring out the second. It's not clear to me how to build off of function types.

I tried using intersection:

```
type FancyFoo = Foo & {
  HELLO :string,
  test :() => mixed
}
```

However, this approach fails:

```
// Errors:
2: type FancyFoo = Foo & {
                         ^ property `HELLO` of object type. Property not found in
7: const fooFn :FancyFoo = () => ({ id: '...', type: '...' });
                           ^ function

2: type FancyFoo = Foo & {
                         ^ property `test` of object type. Property not found in
7: const fooFn :FancyFoo = () => ({ id: '...', type: '...' });
                           ^ function
```

How do I define a `FancyFoo` function type that "extends" `Foo` but also includes the extra properties?

[Link to Flow Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKAKAlMgfFA3gKCigEsATKALgGdgAnYgOwHMAaQqUSSm+5-AX3ydo8OAFEAHsGSwEUAGR52ACTEAZNQHludRq3bAINShmxQAtsQkRSA-PgDGcBsYBmCGA0qjJ0lKaQcVFwSUgooAHIAOhiIlg5wCHDo2Kh+dABufHc4TwBtCNUNTQiAXRkIgHVNACU1ABEIrJz8iMMaMpkAnFx+LPwAegGOAAtiKigqEbgAVwAbcjAAQyoqbI8GDGaNqKKtbdyGKPbgLfsh0fHJ6fnyVyXiOfXDqMqazQA5AHEDzyiAd1oziYWyAA)

---

**UPDATE**

Here's a more specific example for what I'm trying to do:

```
type Foo = () => { id :string, type :string }

export function getFancyFoo(type :string) :FancyFoo {

  const id :string = randomId();
  const foo :Foo = getFoo(id, type);

  ['A', 'B', 'C'].forEach((thing :string) => {
    foo[thing.toUpperCase()] = thing.toUpperCase();
    foo[thing.toLowerCase()] = () => { /* function that does fancy thing */ };
  });

  return foo;
}
```

The `getFancyFoo` function will first get a `Foo` function, and then decorate/enhance it with extra properties. At the end of the function, `foo` will look like this (Chrome Dev Tools):

[image: FancyFoo example]

`FancyFoo` is a `Foo` function, but it also has the extra properties added to it. I'm stuck on defining the `FancyFoo` function type.

Comment: I know that you can do the following: `type FooExt = { (): Object, HELLO :string, test :() => mixed}`. This defines a callable object (i.e. function) that has two additional properties. But that would only work for a new definition, not existing an existing definition I think.

Comment: Oooh, I didn't know about the `(): Object` notation. Where is this in the docs?

Comment: Why do you want to associate data with a function in the first place? Javascript has closures or generator functions if you need some sort of state.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Callable Object](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/functions/#toc-callable-objects) syntax, e.g.

```
type OutputInterceptorType = {|
  <T>(routine: () => Promise<T> | T): Promise<T>,
  output: ''
|};
```